# Thread 1: Program received signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c, object

I just have a simple code to practice Object C..
I am not sure why I can this "WARNING"?
My code is below

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface MyClass : NSObject {
@private
    NSDate *mdate;
}

@property (retain) NSDate *mdate;

@end
```

==================================

```
#import "MyClass.h"


@implementation MyClass

@synthesize mdate;

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code here.
        mdate = [[NSDate date] autorelease];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

=============================================

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "MyClass.h"

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    MyClass *mclass = [[MyClass alloc]init];
    NSDate *myBirthday;
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy/MM/dd"];
    myBirthday=[dateFormat dateFromString:@"1990/09/02"];

    [mclass setMdate:myBirthday];
    NSLog(@"My Birthday is %@",[mclass mdate]);
    // insert code here...
    NSLog(@"Hello, World!");

    [mclass release];
    //[dateFormat release];

    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

and in [pool drain] -> i got the message after I ran.

I am really newbie on Object C. Could someone please explain what I missed?
I think this cause my memory management(?)
btw, I was writing this for console.

Comment: You don't release the pool object, which is a memory leak, although the app terminates directly after it, it's better to release it instead of draining it. Releasing it will drain it for you.

Comment: Actually, `drain` drains the pool and releases it.  That line of code, at least, is correct.

Answer (score 5):

Mdate is over released.

In general, your memory management is quite wrong.  Read the "Cocoa memory management guide" as it explains the relatively simple rules clearly.

Answer (score 2):

you should not release the object which are neither alloced or init by you.

```
mdate = [[NSDate date] autorelease]; //Wrong statement.
```

In your **init** function of `MyClass`, you should not call `autorelease` on the `NSDate` object,**which you don't create ,** you get it from iOS framework and iOS own the responsibility to release it.

Here is the case of your `mdate` object  **overreleased**.

```
mdate = [NSDate date]; //Correct statement.
```

Read the Apple [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html)

Answer (score 0):

If your .h file is defined like this:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MyClass : NSObject {
@private
    NSDate *mdate;
}

@property (retain) NSDate *mdate;

@end
```

Then your .m file should look like this:

```
#import "MyClass.h"

@implementation MyClass

@synthesize mdate;

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // mdate = [[NSDate date] autorelease];  WRONG
        // mdate = [NSDate date];  WRONG

        mdate = [[NSDate date] retain];  CORRECT
        // mdate = [[NSDate alloc] init];  CORRECT
        // mdate = [[[[NSDate alloc] init] autorelease] retain]; CORRECT (but weird)

        // self.mdate = [NSDate date];  CORRECT

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [mdate release]; // NECESSARY
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```